# Take a full size screenshot using selenium with current date using python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

After my script is done I need to take a screenshot of the site, with the current date.
I tried to use `driver.save_screenshot('site header' +'date'+'.png')` but the result is a screenshot of the entire screen. performing `driver.maximize_window` will screenshot but without scrolling down.
I tried using

```
`pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.press('j')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.press('p')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')`
```

but I can't sendkeys 'capture full size screenshot', plus, with this option I wont be able to change the screenshot name with current date.

any suggestions?